# add legend and tooltip using xaml.cs file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am drawing the charts in xaml.cs file such as

```
chart = new RadCartesianChart();
chart.Name = "Chart";
chart.Margin = new Thickness(10,20,10,20);
chart.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
chart.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray);
chart.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
ObservableCollection<MultiSeries> multiseries = mainWindowViewModel.GetSeies(Row, Col);
multiseries.ToList().ForEach(series =>
{
  chart.Series.Add(SeriesHelper.getLineSeries(series));
}
chart.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, Col);
chart.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, Row);
ChartGrid.Children.Add(chart);
```

and I am trying to add tooltip and legend to this chart 
but I don't no how to add tooltip and legend .

Comment: See the [ToolTip Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltip(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN, or use more *words* in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this statement:

```
chart.Behaviors.Add(new ChartTooltipBehavior());
```